# Error with "new google.maps.directionService()" on google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm tryng to do a map with google maps api and jquery-mobile, the map I want to do it's a directions map. I've two GPS coordinate and I wanto to show the way betwen the two points when the map is initialized. This is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>
```

and the code of the script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

var dirService;

var render;

function calcolateRoute(){

   dirService = new google.maps.directionService();

   var myOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng( 46.448327,12.37707);

   var myDestination = new google.maps.LatLng( 46.443993,12.388498)

   var mapOptions = {

  zoom:7,

  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

  center: myOrigin};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  var renderOpt = { map:map };
render = new google.maps.directionRenderer(renderOpt);

var requestRoute = {

        origin: myOrigin,

        destination: myDestination,

        travelMode: google.maps.travelMode.BICYCLING};

dirService.route(requestRoute, function(result, status){

if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){

    render.setDirection(result);                        

}else{

            alert('ERROR ');}

});



}
</script>
```

When the browser render the page i receive this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

at the line

```
dirService = new google.maps.directionService();
```

I don't understand why the script return the error.... Someone can help me?
Sorry for my bad english!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are spelling the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService) incorrectly

Should be:

```
dirService = new google.maps.directionsService();
```

Not:

```
dirService = new google.maps.directionService();
```

Comment: The same errore is in the line where i call
   directionRenderer
right call is
   directionsRenderer

Comment: Sorry but I've another question about this script, now all is right but the script return ZERO_RESULTS, the GPS coordinates are correct and tested in google maps, why I receive this return value?

Comment: Don't know.  [Those coordinates return a route for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=(46.448327,12.37707)&addr2=(46.443993,12.388498)&geocode=1&geocode=2)

Comment: How do you have test the coordinate?

Comment: I took them from your posted code.  Are they not correct?  `var myOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng( 46.448327,12.37707); var myDestination = new google.maps.LatLng( 46.443993,12.388498)`

Comment: Yes, they are! But what is the way you have used for the test? Have you tested the route with travelMode: oogle.maps.travelMode.BICYCLING?

Comment: Nope.  Missed that.  That does return ZERO_RESULTS.  Both walking or driving modes work (return a route, not ZERO_RESULTS).

Comment: The travelMode was the problem, if I put DRIVING the return status is OK, but now the problem is that I haven't a way betwee the two piont, I see a simple map... why?

Comment: You did something else wrong.  That should be another question as you will need to provide your latest code.